# How to release the NSDATA from AVAudioPlayer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, avaudioplayer

Here I used to play the songs using `AVAudioPlayer Framework`. Hopefully it's playing, but if I click on other songs from the Songslist I will check the condition :

```
if(player.isPlaying == YES)
{
    [player stop];
    // And also i need to release or remove the existing NSDATA from the Player. otherwise the player won't release the existing data. So the memory pressure occurring in my project. 
}
self.audioPlayer = [self.audioPlayer initWithData:m_currentMusic.fileData error:&error];
[self.audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
[self.audioPlayer play];
```

Answer (score 2):

`AVAudioPlayer#data` is a read-only non-retained property. So, the data is not retained and you have no need to releease it (it's `assigned` as by default).

However, as I said, it's `read-only` so you can't set it if you wish to change tracks. You also shouldn't call `init...` on an already initialied object, as in your code:

```
self.audioPlayer=[self.audioPlayer initWithData:m_currentMusic.fileData error:&error];
```

I believe the intended action for what you want is to relesae your existing `self.audioPlayer` and re-create a new one, as follows:

```
// stop player as in your original code...
[self.audioPlayer release];
AVAudioPlayer *newPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:m_currentMusic.fileData error:&error];
self.audioPlayer = newPlayer;
[self.audioPlayer setDelegate:self];
[newPlayer release];
```

Note that the `release` will cause your original track `data` to be reclaimed (as it's non-retained).

See also [Core Audio Overview](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/CoreAudioEssentials/CoreAudioEssentials.html)

Comment: Here I don't want to create again & again alloc. Because the player created only one time.I want to replace the nsdata. And also I used  [self.audioplayer stop]; [self.audioplayer release];. This code its working for different songs again if i click one more song"The compiler tells the BAD ACCESS".

Comment: `[self.audioPlayer release]` is releasing your `AVAudioPlayer`. It's unusable after that as at some point the memory is going to be reclaimed (so you can't be playing a track at that point or all sorts of nasties will occur). Unfortunately, you can't reset just the data either as the property `AVAudioPlayer#data` is marked as `readonly` (can't be set). See [AVAudioPlayer class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Chapters/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAudioPlayer/data). You have to reset your player.

Comment: BAD ACCESS = You released the memory but were still using the player (as you describde in your comment). Perhaps see also [this Cocoa memory management guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html) (note it's Cocoa though).

Comment: Actually, another consideration might be to use the delegate to release your player when the player actually has confirmed it's stopped playing your track. This ensures no memory nasties but, either way, you have to release and re-create your player.